# Check if all elements in nested list are positive or negative in python

Tags: python, nested-lists

I am trying to use a list comprehension to find the nested list whose elements are all positive, but I am not sure how to phrase the conditional to check all the values in the nested list for the list comprehension.

```
records = [[-167.57, 4.0, 61.875, -100.425],
 [-1.75, 3.75, 4.0],
 [7612.875, 10100.0, 74.25, 1.75, 61.875],
 [-2333.37, -5404.547500000001, -5178.645833333333, 97.0, 167.57],
 [-96.99999999999997, -5277.999999999999, -4998.5, 74.25, 3.75]]

answer = [i for i in records if (n < 0 for n in i)]
answer
```

I think this is the statement I am trying to turn into code: "if all n > 0 for n in i, return index i"

edit: Output would be to return the index of the corresponding row of all positive numbers

Comment: What exactly is the expected output? Get the first row? Get all rows? Figure out if such rows exist?

Comment: Output would be to return the index of the corresponding row of all positive numbers

Comment: Thanks, can you make that clear in your question please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are close. Imagine how you would do this in a loop:

```
for index, row in enumerate(records):
    if all(col > 0 for col in row): 
        print(index)
```

The `if` condition with `all` returns True if all elements are positive only. Now put this into list comprension form:

```
answer = [
    index 
    for index, row in enumerate(records) 
    if all(col > 0 for col in row)
]
# [2]
```

---

List comprehensions are optimized versions of for loops  specifically made for creating lists. There is usually a one-to-one translation between a loop generating a list, and a list comprehension. My advice when you are stuck on list comp syntax is to take a step back and visualize what this looks like as a simple for loop. Here are two important rules of optimization (as told to me by my mentor in university):

1. Don't optimize
2. Don't optimize yet

Answer (score 1):

You can use `all` to check whether all elements satisfy a given condition, e.g.

```
answer = [all(n > 0 for n in lst) for lst in records]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) built-in method that

> Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty)

- for all negative

  ```
  answer = [all(n < 0 for n in i) for i in records] # [False, False, False, False, False]
  ```
- for all positive

  ```
  answer = [all(n > 0 for n in i) for i in records] # [False, False, True, False, False]
  ```

---

To get indexes of *all-positive rows*, combine with `enumerate`

```
answer = [idx for idx,row in enumerate(records) if all(n > 0 for n in row)] # [2]
```